# If $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$, compute $f^{1999}(2000)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, contest-math

I have observed $f^{n}(x)f^{n-1}(x)f^{n-2}(x)=-1$, and expanding, I get $f^{2000}(x)=-\dfrac{2000}{1999}$. However, this is not a very neat solution, and that makes me wonder if it is correct at all. Please help.

Answer (score 11):

If $f^n(x)$ denotes the $n$-th iteration of $f$,
then
$$f^2(x)=\frac{x-1}{x}$$
and
$$f^3(x)=x.$$
Therefore $f^{3n}(x)=x$ and so $f^{1999}(x)=f(x)$ etc.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

$$f^{2}(x)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-x}}=\frac{x-1}{x}$$

$$f^4(x)=f^2(f^2(x))=\frac{\frac{x}{1-x}-1}{\frac{x-1}{x}}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

$$f^{3n}(x)=f^{3n-4}(f^4(x))=f^{3n-4}(f(x))=f^{3(n-1)}(x)$$

Applying this $n$ times,

$$\implies f^{3n+r}(x)=f^r(x)$$

Thus we can say that $$f^{1999}(x)=f^{3k+1}(x)=f(x)$$

Comment: $f^8(x)=f^2(x)!=f(x)$, so $f^{4n} \neq f$.

Comment: Or rather, $f^4(x) = f(x)$ does not imply $f^{4k}(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: @guest I have edited and corrected it. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @KennyLau I have corrected it. Thanks to you too. :)